# Subset data frame by ID but within 7 days

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame with two variables `ID` and `arrival`. Here is head of my data frame:

```
head(sun_2)
Source: local data frame [6 x 2]

         ID  arrival
      (chr)   (dats)
1 027506905 01.01.15     
2 042363988 01.01.15    
3 026050529 01.01.15    
4 028375072 01.01.15    
5 055384859 01.01.15     
6 026934233 01.01.15
```

How could I subset data by `ID` which has arrive within `7` days?

Comment: Within 7 days of what? The first observation for each ID? Also a `dput(head(sun_2))` would be a more helpful way to present your data.

Comment: can you provide an example of your output? It'd be great reproduced your question following the guidelines in this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for bad post... Yes, within 7 days from first observation. There are some observations (same IDs) which are duplicated, but I am intrested only in that one, wich arrive withih 7 days from first observation.

Comment: Please make your question reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

So like a lot of the other folks were saying, without more information (what the original observation looks like for example) we can't get at exactly what your issue is without making some assumptions.

I assumed that you have a column of data that indicates the original Date? And that these rows are formatted `as.Date`.

```
#generate Data
Data <- data.frame(ID = as.character(1394:2394),
               arrival = sample(seq(as.Date('2015/01/01'), as.Date('2016/01/01'), by = 'day'), 1001, replace = TRUE))

# Make the "Original Observation" Variable
delta_times <- sample(c(3:10), 1001, replace = TRUE)
Data$First <- Data$arrival - delta_times
```

this gives me a data set that looks like this

```
    ID    arrival      First
1 1394 2015-11-06 2015-10-28
2 1395 2015-08-04 2015-07-26
3 1396 2015-04-19 2015-04-16
4 1397 2015-05-13 2015-05-03
5 1398 2015-07-18 2015-07-11
6 1399 2015-01-08 2015-01-03
```

If that is the case then the solution is to use `difftime`, like so:

```
# Now we need to make a subsetting variables
Data$diff_times <- difftime(Data$arrival, Data$First, units = "days")
Data$diff_times

within_7 <- subset(Data, diff_times <=7)

max(within_7$diff_times)
Time difference of 7 days
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to be sure given the information you've provided, but I think you could do it like this:

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(arrival < min(arrival) + 7)
```

Comment: Thx! That is exactlly what i wanted to do... It works!

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about how this works?

Comment: I think you're piping the result of the command `group_by` to the command `filter`, but I thought each ID was unique, so I don't know how `group_by` works in this case?